# String magically cuts by itself

Tags: c#, string

I don't understand what is going on. Recently I took [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting) code and edited it a bit. I've found a bug so I've tried to debug it and met weird behaviour. Somewhy 2 strings created from 2 different char arrays consisting of same letters aren't equal and also debug string is cutted.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AlphanumericComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
            return 0;

        int len1 = s1.Length;
        int len2 = s2.Length;
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;

        while (i1 < len1 && i2 < len2)
        {
            char c1 = s1[i1];
            char c2 = s2[i2];

            char[] chunk1 = new char[len1];
            int j1 = 0;
            char[] chunk2 = new char[len2];
            int j2 = 0;

            do
            {
                Debug.Log("1: " + i1 + " _ " + j1 + " _ " + c1); // Seems to be OK.
                chunk1[j1++] = c1;
                i1++;

                if (i1 < len1)
                    c1 = s1[i1];
                else
                    break;
            } while (char.IsDigit(c1) == char.IsDigit(chunk1[0]));

            do
            {
                Debug.Log("2: " + i2 + " _ " + j2 + " _ " + c2); // Seems to be OK.
                chunk2[j2++] = c2;
                i2++;

                if (i2 < len2)
                    c2 = s2[i2];
                else
                    break;
            } while (char.IsDigit(c2) == char.IsDigit(chunk2[0]));

            string str1 = new string(chunk1);
            string str2 = new string(chunk2);
            Debug.Log(str1.CompareTo(str2) + " " + str1 + " " + str2); // "1"?! And also why is string cutted?!

            int result;

            if (char.IsDigit(chunk1[0]) && char.IsDigit(chunk2[0]))
            {
                result = int.Parse(str1).CompareTo(int.Parse(str2));
                //Debug.Log(s1 + " _ " + s2 + " _ " + int.Parse(str1) + " _ " + int.Parse(str2) + " _ " + result);//tmp
                Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", s1, s2, int.Parse(str1), int.Parse(str2), result));//tmp
            }
            else
            {
                result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
                //Debug.Log(s1 + " _ " + s2 + " _ " + str1 + " _ " + str2 + " _ " + result);//tmp
                Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", s1, s2, str1, str2, result));//tmp
            }

            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }

        return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```

I've tried to reload all IDEs but it has brought nothing. My strings which I compare:

```
string[] test = new string[] { "qwe45", "qwe13a" };
```

For the next string sorting works as expected and behaviour differs but cutted debug string bug is still there:

```
string[] test = new string[] { "qwe45", "qwe13" };
```

What am I doing wrong or if I am not, how to workaround this?

**UPDATE:**

Also if I split like this:

```
Debug.Log(str1);
Debug.Log(str2);
```

it shows right stuff, but `CompareTo` still returns some garbage.

Comment: what do you mean by 'cutted debug string'?

Comment: @KevinHooke `Debug.Log(str1.CompareTo(str2) + " " + str1 + " " + str2);` should return `0 qwe qwe`, but it returns `1 qwe`. And then `Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", s1, s2, str1, str2, result));` should return `qwe13a, qwe45, qwe, qwe, 0` but returns `qwe13a, qwe45, qwe`.

Comment: Seems ok to me. Check the output here https://dotnetfiddle.net/QqbTcd

Comment: @failedprogramming Your output is what I should get on my PC. This is very weird, is it Unity bug or something?

Comment: @Necronomicron Sorry, not sure. Missed the Unity3d tag on the question!

Comment: @failedprogramming Maybe it is not related to Unity, but who knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggle to understand what the code is trying to accomplish, but it seems to me that your declaration `char[] chunk1 = new char[len1];` creates a variable that is one character too short.

`len1` is the length of the first input string, in your example (`"qwe45"`) *5*. So `chunk1` will have five chars of memory space, which allows *four* chars of text plus the terminating 0.

Then you copy it into `str1` with `string str1 = new string(chunk1);`, which means that `str1` will now be one char shorter. Isn't that the char you are missing?

Comment: Omg, you are so right. I've changed array to list now. This is what happens when you pick someone's code... Don't get me wrong, I've checked what I copypasted, but somehow forgot about `\0` thing.

Comment: But I wonder why it works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QqbTcd). Unity (partially?) uses C++, I guess this is the reason.